# different way to use binary Serialisation

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I want to serialize a class for which I don't have the source code, 
is there a way to binary serialize this class which does not have the Attribute Serializable in C#?

I'm using the microsoft class to do that
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: can someone want to put a comment before down vote? I could edit my question in the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the [Serializable] attribute you cannot do binary serialization, at least not using the default mechanism.

You can do XmlSerialization, or create your custom serialization process through reflection.

**EDIT** A trick has come to my mind, not sure if it will work

Maybe you can achieve it using Google's protocol buffers, let me explain.

Google has a very light and fast serialization library called protocol buffers, here is the .net implementation: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

If you create a class encapsulating the target class, I belive (not 100% sure) it will serialize it.

Lets assume the class you want to serialze is named ClasToSer, then you can create a class like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Encapsulator
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ClasToSer RealData{ get; set; };    

}
```

Then you can serialize and deserialze with this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using ProtoBuf;

public static class ProtoBuffHelper
{

    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T Objeto)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize<T>(ms, Objeto);
        byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Dispose();
        return data;

    }


    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] Datos)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Datos);
        T inst = Serializer.Deserialize<T>(ms);
        ms.Dispose();
        return inst;

    }
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if it worked.

Comment: the class I try to serialize can already be serialized in xml but I try to reduce the size of the file and the process time

Comment: With Reflection I have no Idea how to do that, I though maybe there is a tier api to do that

Comment: Nope, there is not, through reflection you can enumerate all the properties of a class, then get it's values and save as binary data, but is a very hard and long code (but also you will get very compact data)